# How to write cyrillic letters to a file in Python/Django

Tags: python, django

I have a large form which contains a lot of text. For example, it may contain words in quotation marks like `"Программа"`. When I submit it to the server and try to write the submitted content to a file, I get an error. If I instead replace all cyrillic letters with latin letters, then everything works ok. The problem is obviously on the server side. I guess, if I new how to deal with such strings like `"Текст на кириллице"`, I could solve the problem.

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: The server should return json `{success:true}` and the client responds to this with an alert `Saved!`. With latin letters it works, but with cyrillic letters I see no response from the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write to file unicode string, you must encode it first.

Let's try the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text = u"Текст на кириллице"

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(text)
```

This code will raise an exception

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, just encode the text. One of the most popular encoding is 'utf8':

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text = u"Текст на кириллице"

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(text.encode('utf8'))
```

You must remember the encoding, that was used to encode text, to be able to read it later.
To read the text from file, decode it using same encoding used in writting:

```
with open('outfile.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

print text.decode('utf8')
```

Comment: And if I pass text as a variable, how should I do it? I mean, is this `text = u variable` correct? I do not know the right syntax

Comment: in my examples `text` - is a variable, and `u"Текст на кириллице"` is a variable value

Comment: I mean, I want to have a variable on the right-hand side. Imagine I have a variable which contains this text `Текст на кириллице`. How should I convert it to utf? Just u`variable? Or variable.encode(utf8)?

Comment: Will this work? `text = request.POST['data'] ... fw.write(text.encode('utf8'))`

Comment: text_var = u'{}'.format(variable). Suppose that variable='Текст на кирилица'. And don't forget # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at top of the file.

Comment: @stalk, kpacn. Thank you, guys! I will check it right now